# ¿Cómo funciona este tipo de variables?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber cómo es su estructura, cuando usarlas y cómo se hace para llamar cada dato que está dentro.

```
"texto": {
nombre: "";
apeliido: "";
// ETC...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partamos de la premisa de tratar de entender lo que es un JSON, ya que aquello que tienes ahí es un JSON mal formado, JSON es un acrónimo de `JavaScript Object Notation`, JSON fue tomado de los objetos originales de javascript y actualmente es usado en el transporte de datos sin depender de la plataforma (Gracias al usuario `BetaM` por este maravilloso aporte y muchos mas), los json que se ven en su mínima expresión se ven como unas simples llaves:

```
{}
```

Si bien el formato `JSON` fue tomado de `JS` esto no significa que `JSON` y los objetos en `JS` sean lo mismo debido a que en `JSON` hay ciertas restricciones y cosas a tener en cuenta, por ejemplo tener en cuenta que si es independiente del lenguaje entonces la información transportable debe ser información que todos los lenguajes de programación puedan interpretar o parsear sin embargo, javascript es capaz de interpretar estos `JSON` de manera nativa.

Para clarificar las restricciones que se toman en `JSON`, el cuál es una evolución estricta de los objetos nativos de javascript y tambien aquellos formatos que son alojados por este formato podemos ver el siguiente enlace:

[JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Una de las restricciones directas de `JSON` por ejemplo es que el uso de las comillas simples esta estrictamente prohibido ('), cualquier intento por poner comillas simples en un `JSON` hará automáticamente que este falle, así que esta es una diferencia entre `JSON` y `JS`.

Siguiendo con la distinción entre que es un `JSON`, sabemos ya entonces que el formato `JSON` tiene ciertas restricciones respecto a su primitiva forma de `JS`, esto para unificar un poco el transporte de datos, ahora bien que pasa si intentamos cargar un `JSON` desde un lenguaje de programación diferente a javascript?, por ejemplo `PHP`, lo que pasara es que el contenido será leido como un documento de texto plano, un binario u otro formato de lectura de datos (dependerá de como le indiquemos que lo lea) directamente.

Haciendo que el `JSON` aún sea tratable desde ese lenguaje de programación como una cadena de texto.

pero y que pasa si intentamos leer directamente un `JSON` desde `javascript`??, como javascript soporta nativamente el formato `JSON`, si el formato `JSON` esta correctamente construido y no contiene errores, pasara de inicios lo mismo, es decir, el archivo será leído como un `documento de texto`, un `binario`, un `blob` o algo que le especifiquemos para leerlo.

Sin embargo, que pasa si por ejemplo al obtener estos datos, ya sea como por ejemplo una cadena de texto usamos la función para convertir a json?, el resultado es un `objeto nativo de javascript`, un `Object`.

Como lo podemos ver en el siguiente ejemplo:

Primero partamos de tener un archivo `.json` llamado json.json y dentro de este nuestro objeto:

```
{
    "nombre":"Juan",
    "apellido":"Perez"
}
```

Ahora supongamos que queremos cargarlo en nuestro javascript, entonces usemos `fetch` para ello por ejemplo:

```js
fetch("./json.json").then(res =>{
    /*
      Se convierte en json, pero si json según es un string tecnicamente no
      debería retornar una cadena?, esto retorna un Object directamente, es JS interpretando el JSON directamente.
    */
    return res.json();
}).then(json =>{
    /*
        Como vemos al hacer fetch y convertir nuestra respuesta en json,
        en vez de obtener un string que tecnicamente sería el JSON, 
        obtenemos es un object debido a que javascript interpreta nativamente
        este formato.
    */
    console.log("\nJSON tomado desde un archivo .json");
    console.log(json);
    console.log(typeof json);    //object
});

/*
    Pasemos entonces a intentar hacer lo mismo pero desde el propio js, y no desde
    un .json:
*/
const json = {
    "nombre":"Juan",
    "apellido":"Perez"
}

console.log("JSON desde js:");
console.log(json);
console.log(typeof json);
```

El resultado de fetch no lo podemos ver en el snippet por supuesto, pero esencialmente ambos retornan lo mismo, un `Object`, ahora bien, según la especificación de `Body.json` de parte de la pagina oficial de mozilla developers:

[Body.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

Podemos citar las siguientes palabras:

> The json() method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads
>   it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with the result
>   of parsing the body text as JSON.

Traducido al español:

> El metodo json() de Body coge un flujo de datos y lo lee hasta
>   completarse. Retorna una promesa que se resuelve con el resultado de
>   analizar **el cuerpo del texto como un JSON**

Si `JSON` es un flujo de datos y al parsearlo a un `JSON`... significa entonces que javascript usa JSON?, respuesta:

Javascript usa su propia versión nativa de `JSON` (recordemos que `JSON` viene de JS y digo su propia versión nativa porque ésta si permite cosas que `JSON` no, por ejemplo, en el documento llamado `json.json` teniamos:

```
{
    "nombre":"Juan",
    "apellido":"Perez"
}
```

Si pasamos exactamente esto mismo a un archivo javascript cuidando de asignarselo a algo:

```js
const miJSON = {
    "nombre":"Juan",
    "apellido":"Perez"
}

console.log(miJSON);
```

Vemos que es el mismo formato y lo interpreta javascript, lo unico que cambia es que se lo asignamos a algo para que no quede anónimo.

Podemos hacer otro ejemplo con un json exactamente igual anonimo, pero esta vez dentro de una función:

```js
function getJSON(){
  //Se ve exactamente igual al formato JSON aquí
  return {
    "nombre":"Juan",
    "apellido":"Perez"
  }
}

//Y javascript lo interpreta directamente sin problema.
console.log(getJSON());
```

Entonces en que casos puedo decir que `JSON` es por ejemplo una cadena de texto y en que casos puedo decir que no?, pues si partimos de esta premisa si hicieramos esta comparación con por ejemplo una `imagen`, una imagen puede ser leida de diferentes formas y el formato puede diferir, pero lo que le da sentido a la imagen y sus datos es aquello que puede interpretarlos, aquello que puede leerlos, por ejemplo la galería de nuestro `SO`.

Por lo que en este sentido podemos decir que mientras que el JSON y sus datos aún no estén siendo interpretados por algo que les de un sentido concreto, pueden ser cualquier cosa, datos binarios, texto o como sea que lo hayamos leído.

Sin embargo, al ser este un tipo:

```
application/json
```

Que pasa si hacemos que el navegador interprete un json?, el resultado será algo parecido a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo mismo que sucede en javascript, al inicio leemos los datos a manera de string, pero al ser interpretados por javascript pasan a ser un:

```
Object
```

Ahora bien, dicho esto pasemos a las cosas básicas de los objetos en javascript, (recordemos que los objetos en javascript usan una versión primitiva y propia del formato `JSON` actual que **NO** es directamente **JSON**, pero que puede ser interpretado como tál en `JS` de manera nativa).

Entonces hablando un poco de `JSON` el formato como tal, podemos usar tu ejemplo:

```
"texto": {
   nombre: "";
   apeliido: "";
   // ETC...
}
```

Si tomamos esto como un `JSON` literal es decir como una simple cadena de texto, entonces no habría nada que hacer con este formato, es decir, solo se puede usar como una simple cadena, y no se podrá acceder como tal a ninguna de sus 'propiedades'.

Pero si lo interpretamos con `JS`, tendriamos errores, pero para poder darnos cuenta de estos errores, primero deberemos aprender sobre los componentes de un `objeto`, asumiendo que haya sido interpretado el `JSON` en `javascript`.

**Componentes de un objeto JSON (interpretado por JS):**

- **Propiedades o llaves**: Son la parte izquierda de un par de valores separados por ':' en el objeto, estos figuran el como acceder al otro extremo que sería el valor de la propiedad.
- **Valores**: son la parte derecha de un par de valores separados por ':', a este valor o valores se puede acceder mediante la propiedad o propiedades del objeto.
- **funciones o metodos**: la descripción de estos dependera si nos encontramos en una clase o no, pero asumiendo que no nos encontramos formalmente en una clase se le llamaria funciones, de lo contrario se les llama metodos, son partes de código ejecutable reutilizable.

Ahora bien, ya que sabemos sobre los componentes de nuestro objeto interpretado como JSON en js, podemos proceder a ver en que te haz equivocado, en primeras:

- La separación entre propiedades de un objeto JSON siempre se hacen con el simbolo (,) (coma) y no el (;) (punto y coma).
- Tienes definido una propiedad texto que no hace parte de ningún objeto.
- La ultima propiedad de un objeto nunca lleva nada al final (tienes ; al final).

Entonces de acuerdo a estas premisas, si quiseramos corregir tu `JSON` quedaría así:

```
{
  "texto": {
    nombre: "",
    apeliido: ""
  }
}
```

**Como accedemos a los valores y metodos de un objeto JSON desde JS?**

**Para acceder a un valor:** Para hacerlo hay dos formas, la primera es usar el nombre del objeto seguido de un punto y este a su vez seguido de la propiedad del objeto de la cuál requerimos su valor:

```js
const objetoJSON = {
  "texto": {
    nombre: "Juan",
    apeliido: "Perez"
  }
}

console.log(objetoJSON.texto);
```

La segunda es usando el nombre del objeto seguido de corchetes y dentro de los corchetes poner el nombre de la propiedad del objeto a manera de `string`:

```js
const objetoJSON = {
  "texto": {
    nombre: "Juan",
    apeliido: "Perez"
  }
}

console.log(objetoJSON["texto"]);
```

**NOTA**: Para el formato **JSON** en sí, esta estrictamente prohibido que las 'propiedades' no esten entre comillas dobles, mientras que en un objeto JSON interpretado por JS, esto no es necesariamente así, por lo que algo como esto es valido **solo en js**:

```js
const objetoJSON = {
  texto: {
    nombre: "Juan",
    apeliido: "Perez"
  }
}

console.log(objetoJSON["texto"]);
```

Como vemos la propiedad texto de nuestro objeto `JSON` no tiene comillas dobles pero funciona, en `JSON` esto automaticamente sería invalido.

**Accediendo y ejecutando funciones...**

Las funciones no estan disponibles en el formato `JSON`, pero dentro del propio formato de objeto nativo de `JS` predecesor a `JSON` sí, por lo que no podemos acceder a metodos de un `JSON` oficial, pero si a aquellos creados por nosotros desde `JS`:

```js
const objetoJSON = {
  saludame: function(){
    console.log("Hola!");
  }
}

objetoJSON.saludame()
```

como vemos solo debemos acceder a nuestro metodo y ejecutarlo con unos parentesis.

**Cuando conviene usar un objeto JSON de JS (interpretado por JS)?**

Conviene usar este tipo de objetos para cuando queremos usar pares de valores para relacionar entre sí, un valor con otro, donde nuestros valores a relacionar son las `llaves o propiedades` y el `valor` de nuestra propiedad, algo así como los `diccionarios` que contiene el lenguaje de programación `python` o los arreglos asociativos de `PHP`.

Normalmente este tipo de objetos se combinan con los arreglos, para crear una lista de objetos `parecidos pero esencialmente diferentes` con esto a lo que me refiero es que pese a que un objeto pueda llegarse a ver igual que otro en cierto momento, si no tienen exactamente la misma referencia, entonces ambos objetos serán diferentes el uno al otro, pese a que tengan las mismas propiedades y valores entre sí.

Un ejemplo viable de esto de arriba es si quisieramos por ejemplo tener un listado de nuestros compañeros de clase y luego por ejemplo imprimir el nombre de cada uno:

```js
const classMates = [
  {
    nombre: "Brayan",
    apellido: "Garcia",
    edad: 26
  },
  {
    nombre: "Juan",
    apellido: "Lopez",
    edad: 26
  },
  {
    nombre: "Bill",
    apellido: "Gates",
    edad: 26
  },
];

for(let i = 0; i < classMates.length; i++){
  console.log(classMates[i].nombre);
}
```

Como vemos, el combinar un arreglo con varios objetos parecidos, nos facilita un poco esta tarea.

Comment: JSON es el concepto y el nombre que se le dio formalmente, objeto normalmente es como se le llama a la instancia de ese JSON en javascript, pero no necesariamente el JSON, ya que todo en javascript deriva de Object.

Comment: Tecnicamente si, ya que los objetos en javascript son una instancia de la clase Object, del cuál derivan por ejemplo también las functions (si imprimes el prototype de una function es Object).

Comment: Gracias por la info Beta, leí el post, sin embargo solo difiere es el formato pero llevandolo a realmente el concepto del formato JSON. según esta información: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON el formato JSON fue extendido de javascript, es decir, hace parte nativa de JS, y la clase Object usa este formato para crear objetos, es mas, ahí mismo en el enlace se dictan las siguientes palabras:

Comment: Por eso, osea, lo que queria dar entender cuando uso la palabra objeto, es que javascript hace uso nativamente de la estructura con la que trabaja JSON, por eso digo que los objetos de javascript que conforman una estructura como json se pueden interpretar como tales, debido a que si tratas de usar los valores de estos json desde javascript directamente funcionara debido a que javascript lo interpreta nativamente como un JSON.

Comment: Gracias Beta, considero este un debate, no una discusión, una aportación de ideas, para clarificar todo, pero muchas gracias por la información, si, considero que tengo equivocaciones al respecto y haré mas tarde aquellas correciones... por ejemplo tienes razón en eso de los arreglos y de pronto otras cosas que no se clarifican bien, gracias por tu ayuda, aportaciones e ideas, las tomare en cuenta, las leere mas en detalle y haré las respectivas correciones a mi respuesta.