# como mostrar un msj viniendo de codigo php de otra pagina?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo dos paginas php una la vista del cliente como ejemplo crear_rol.php y tengo otro que tiene la programación por ejemplo Guardar_rol.php y quiero devolver un mensaje que al llenar el primer documento y vaya a la validaciones del segundo muestre el msj . no quiero hacer con variable de session o con enviar variable de url.

```html
        if ($existe['rol']==1)
    {
 
echo"
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  toastr.info('El Rol ". $Rol ." ya existe')




});

</script>";


    }
```

el mensaje me lo muestra pero no me regresa a la pantalla anterior e igual probe con este codigo con la salvedad que solo me envia a la pagina sin mostrar el mensaje, hay alguna solucion.

```html
echo"
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  toastr.info('El Rol ". $Rol ." ya existe').then( window.location = '../vistas/crear_rol_vista.php')




});

</script>";
```

Comment: Hmmmm decir que se considera una muy mala practica de seguridad mezclar html con php, y mas aun mezclar scripts de javascript con php, tengo motivos para decirlo, pero bueno, eso es una explicacion algo larga...

Comment: Porque no hacer las validaciones en el mismo archivo??, el primer archivo se encarga de algo mas??

Comment: el primero es vista nada mas osea html , y el segundo es la programacion pura de php , eso indica que por el ejemplo yo meto un rol llamado prueba y ya exista en la base entonces me debe de tirar un msj que diga "el rol ya existe" y el problema que tengo es ese que al momento de validar no puedo mandar el msj  ya que o me muestra el msj y me quedo en la pagina en blanco de la programacion o con la otra opcion me manda a la pagina pero sin msj

Comment: Si tu otra pagina se encarga de tratar el contenido y revisar si algo existe en la base de datos... porque no responder con un json??, si el segundo codigo no contiene html entonces puede ser usado como enviador de datos a la vista, donde te encargarias de recoger el mensaje con la respuesta traida con ajax y listo, muestras el mensaje ya sea con un alert o con un elemento personalizado y estilizado en tu vista...

Comment: soy principiante en esto , y no tengo los conocimientos de ajax, podrias ayudarme en pasarme un ejemplo simple para poder verificarlo?

Comment: por supuesto, he añadido una respuesta que talvez ayude a comprender mejor esto de ajax y tambien a entender que es lo que se supone se deberia hacer en la parte de ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Tenemos nuestros dos archivos, el archivo `a.php` que es nuestra vista y el archivo `b.php` que es la lógica del servidor.

Supongamos que en tu archivo `a.php` tienes el siguiente contenido directamente en alguna parte de tu archivo:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

  const button = document.getElementById("enviar");
  const form = document.getElementById("formEnviarDatos");
  const nombre = document.getElementsByName("nombre")[0];
  const edad = document.getElementsByName("edad")[0];
  
  button.addEventListener("click", e =>{
  
    //Prevenimos que nos lleve al archivo b.php
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //Obtenemos lo que el usuario puso en los input y lo añadimos a data
    //Que sera enviada por ajax al archivo b.php
    const dataToSend = new FormData();
    dataToSend.append("nombre", nombre.value);
    dataToSend.append("edad", edad.value);
    
    //Creamos una nueva peticion ajax:
    const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    //Cuando b.php nos devuelva una respuesta la usamos en a.php
    ajax.onload = ()=>{
      const responseData = JSON.parse(ajax.response);
      alert(responseData.msg);
    }
    
    ajax.onerror = ()=>{
      alert("Ha ocurrido un error en la peticion!");
    }
    
    //Abrimos la peticion hacia b.php y la enviamos.
    ajax.open("POST", form.action);
    ajax.send(dataToSend);
  });
  
}
```

```html
<form action = "b.php" id = "formEnviarDatos">
  
  <input type = "text" name = "nombre" placeholder = "nombre"><br>
  <label for = "edad">edad: </label><input type = "number" name = "edad" value = "0"><br>
  <button id = "enviar">Enviar!</button>
  
</form>
```

Este formulario debes analizarlo muy bien, por ejemplo en el `action` del form pusimos `b.php` el cual es el archivo que se encarga de procesar tu data, y en javascript extraemos el contenido del atributo action para poder enviar datos por medio de `ajax` a traves de una peticion `POST` hacia el archivo `b.php`.

**en b.php tendrias:**

```
<?php

   /*
      Obtenemos los valores enviados por POST aquí en este archivo,
      estos son los campos que yo decidí usar para obtener en este archivo
      sin embargo tu puedes mandar hacia aca cualquier otro tipo de info
      y se recibe de esta manera puesto que usamos POST, de lo contrario
      debes usar GET, si enviaste los datos por GET.
   */
   $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
   $edad   = $_POST["edad"];

   //Esto sera enviado devuelta como respuesta a tu archivo a.php en ajax
   //cuando se ejecute la funcion onload (se ejecuta automaticamente al enviar)
   //la peticion ajax desde a.php
   $response;
   $message;

   //Haces los procesos usuales de mirar si en la base de datos
   //existe o no ya un rol igual, supongamos que tu ya guardaste esta
   //info en una variable:
   $existe = true;

   //si existe enviamos un contenido, si no enviamos otro, por supuesto deberas
   //usar la variable $Rol que ya poseias en tu codigo original.
   if($existe){
      $message = "El Rol " . $Rol . " ya existe";
   }else{
      $message = "Rol añadido con exito!";
   }

   //Esto es lo que realmente se encargara de enviarte una respuesta como json
   //hacia el archivo a.php como respuesta de ajax.
   echo json_encode(["msg" => $message]);
?>
```

En caso de que no estes familiarizado con el formato `json`, esto deberas consultarlo en una pregunta aparte, puesto que este tema es muy extenso, de hecho tengo una respuesta acerca de el formato `JSON`, por si deseas verla adjuntare la respuesta en los comentarios.

Comment: Aqui se encuentra la pregunta que contiene informacion acerca del formato json, por si estas interesado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/349508/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-este-tipo-de-variables/349542#349542